# Suppress/Disable Log calls from third party library

Tags: java, android, logging

How can I suppress any Log calls from a third party library? I found [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#isLoggable(java.lang.String,%20int)) in the android docs, but I could not make it work.

> Checks to see whether or not a log for the specified tag is loggable at the specified level. The default level of any tag is set to INFO. This means that any level above and including INFO will be logged. Before you make any calls to a logging method you should check to see if your tag should be logged. You can change the default level by setting a system property: 'setprop log.tag. ' Where level is either VERBOSE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, ASSERT, or SUPPRESS. SUPPRESS will turn off all logging for your tag. You can also create a local.prop file that with the following in it: 'log.tag.=' and place that in /data/local.prop.

I tried to put it into the local.properties file with

```
log.tag.ThirdPartyClass=SUPPRESS
```

But that does not work. I am not even sure if that gets into the app at all.

Comment: For what it is worth (2 years later), I had the same problem and couldn't figure out a solution.  Fortunately, the third party library has a generous open source license, so I just edited out the annoying log statements.  Disappointed that Google didn't provide an easier way to do this.